# Pass a Value to AjaxStart Event

Tags: jquery

I am using `ajaxStart()` in order to load a loading popup screen for every AJAX call. The text I have given in the popup is `loading! Please wait`.

I need to change the text based on the screen. For example I have a screen which is doing some calculations on an AJAX call. Then the popup should be like `System is doing the calculation! Please wait`.

How can I do this using the `ajaxStart()` functionality?

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { 
  $("#modal").modal('show') 
})
```

Comment: Cna you show us what you have done

Comment: $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#modal" ).modal('show')
}).. In the modal I have given a default text as "Loading! Please wait".

Comment: from the doc http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ looks like there is not any argument passed in the callback. So I think it's hard to achieve what you want with `ajaxStart`. I don't think you should use that event, you can manage the calls manually or maybe try `.ajaxPrefilter` instead.

Comment: I have more than 45 AJAX calls and I would like to make this loading screen as generic.JUst I pass the text for each calls instead of making lading screen for all AJAX calls.. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a global varible in the file and change the value of the variable every time you send a request;

```
    var messageVar ="Loading.. Please Wait..!!";

    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() { 
    //use messageVar here for your reqmnt;

      $( "#modal" ).modal('show');
      $( "#modal" ).append('<div>'+messageVar +'</div>');

    });.
```

Before ajax call request you can set `messageVar`

Comment: Brilliant answer.. Even I couldn't Think the same.

Comment: if you have just 1 ajax call at a time, this works. But I'm afraid that if there are multiple calls (a sequence of ajax calls), the last one will override the message. Of course in the OP's scenario, that should not happen (because it looks like that the feedback message is for user and there is just one action at a time).

Comment: Only Ajax is asyncronous. JavaSript is not. We can  make use of some function like angular service wrapping the actual $.ajax in which we assign the variable. This will work